# What makes a transaction a SegWit transaction or a non-SegWit transaction?

Tags: segregated-witness

Can we say that if there is at least 1 input with a legacy script then the tx is a non-segwit transaction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends for what purpose.

#### When do segwit validation rules apply?

P2WPKH/P2WSH script validity rules apply on a per-input basis.

Only inputs that spend a segwit output can have a non-empty witness.

#### When is extended serialization used?

BIP144 defines a new way for serializing transactions. It is used whenever at least one input has a non-empty witness. It cannot be used when all witnesses are empty (as is the case for legacy spends).

#### When do the malleability protections afforded by segwit apply?

Only when all (relevant) inputs are segwit inputs do these protections work. However, say a transaction has a multisig segwit input and a legacy single-sig input from yourself, you may be fine, as the single-sig input may be considered non-malleable.

Comment: I didn't understand this part: "Only inputs that spend a segwit output can have a non-empty witness". Does that mean Tx: 96bae089a98234fe4bec93dcd92bfb24acdba84563cffd70d8cba1adf276567b would have no witness if the input was spending a segwit output?

Comment: @Prayank I'm confused by your question. There is a rule that only segwit inputs can have (segregated) witnesses, that's all I'm saying.

Comment: Sorry I read your answer and my question again. My question doesn't make sense. Maybe I need to sleep for a while.

Comment: @PieterWuille Thanks for the answer. Is it correct to say that a segwit transaction is a transaction that spends at least one input with a non-empty witness? It would be nice if you can explain this in layman's terms.

Comment: Well what do you care about when you say "segwit transaction"? You must have a particular definition of that term in mind. I would indeed say that a transaction with at least one segwit input is a segwit transaction, but that's a rather arbitrary convention. If for example by "segwit transaction" you mean "a transaction that is protected from malleability through segwit", then the answer may differ.

Comment: I don't have anything particular in mind, I just wanted to know the difference because many articles/resources mention a segwit transaction or a non-segwit transaction, but I guess there is no clear answer to that. Thank you